# PHP Mycrpyt decrypt problems with bin2hex

Tags: php, encryption, hex, bin

I'm quite new to encryption with PHP. How do I decrypt the output form the following returned encryption?

```
$key = "123456";
$text = "hello";
$cipher_alg = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;

$encrypted_body = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher_alg, $key, $text , MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$encrypted_body_hex = bin2hex($encrypted_body);
$encrypted_body_hex = strtoupper($encrypted_body_hex);
```

I thought if i just worked backwards it would be ok (strtolower, hex2bin, then feed it through mcrypt_decrypt) but im not having any luck.

I think i am getting lost with the bin2hex as hex2bin is not supported on my version of PHP.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested it and it works backwards like you guessed it would. No surprises there.

```
$decrypted_hex = strtolower($encrypted_body_hex);
$decrypted_hex = hex2bin($decrypted_hex);
$text_decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt($cipher_alg, $key, $decrypted_hex, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

`$text_decrypted` then contains "hello".

Perhaps you did not include the same initialisation vector you used for encrypting in your decryption phase?

Create it using `$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(16);` and reuse it for decrypting, or it won't work.

EDIT:

If you have to use PHP <= 5.4, use this [hex2bin replacement](https://gist.github.com/mcrumley/5672621).